# Remove background image on filling the text box

Tags: html, css

I have `textBox` by default it has got background image, now I am able to remove the image on focus using `CSS`, but once the focus is not there image appears, so how to remove this image when then the box is not empty. I prefer doing this using `CSS` rather than `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.

Comment: You mush use js to detect the box is empty or not.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this without using at list a bit of javascript. css doesn't have the ability to check if a box has content

Comment: you can check if the box is empty or not with css too:
`input[type="text"][name="boxname"][value=""]`
and if the box is not empty:
`input[type="text"][name="boxname"]:not([value=""])`
and I think this is possible too:
`input[type="text"][name="boxname"][value!=""]`

Comment: this thing not possible with only css you have to do some javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted to use css only but I can't think of a way to do this without using either js or doing it serverside with PHP (which is probably not an option)
with jquery you can simply use this check:

```
if($('#id_of_box').html() == "") { change css here }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine special CSS Selectors.

CSS 3 includes a ":empty" selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp